# What does "business" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

in a book titled *[Knowledge Management in the Intelligence Enterprise](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=861836)*, the word *business* has been used very often. I don't understand its meaning— maybe it means trade or job processes (organisational intelligence) in intelligence organisations?

For example,

> This is a book about the management of knowledge to produce and deliver a special kind of knowledge: intelligence—that knowledge that is deemed most critical for decision making both in the nation-state and **in business**
>
> Knowledge management refers to the organizational disciplines,
>   processes, and information technologies used to acquire, create, reveal,
>   and deliver knowledge that allows an enterprise to accomplish its mission
>   (achieve its strategic or **business objectives)**.
>
> Driven by the complexity of operations
>   on a global scope, national policies and **business strategies** involve
>   the consideration of many interactive variables
>
> Indeed, intelligence (whether national or **business**) has always involved the
>   management (acquisition, analysis, synthesis, and delivery) of knowledge
>
> Because of these factors, the management of knowledge to produce
>   strategic intelligence has become a necessary and critical function within
>   nations-states and **business enterprises**—requiring changes in culture, processes,
>   and infrastructure to compete.

Comment: I think the best way to understand the word *business* is to spell it as: BUSY-NESS.

Answer (score 2):

This is the ordinary dictionary meaning: a specific commercial enterprise or commercial enterprises generally.

The document you are reading is about "intelligence"; that is, news and information gathered to achieve some specific task.  For example, the Central **Intelligence** Agency is tasked with gathering news and information for the US government.

"Business intelligence" is therefore news and information gathered for conducting your business.  If you are a florist, you need to know the weather (so you know when flowers will be available wholesale).  If you are a restauranteur, you need to know what foods are becoming popular.

Your other phrases, *business strategy*, *business objective*, and so on, can be understood the same way.

Comment: Moreover, it appears to be frequently comparing and contrasting the administration of a nation-state (a non-profit entity which purports to maintain the well-being of its member citizens) to that of a private business (a for-profit entity designed to make money for its owners and investors via the sale of goods or services). (NB: these definitions are just off the top of my head, as an American English speaker.)